# iOS Core Data Migration happens on every app launch

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a migration that is going to a new model where I'm indexing a couple of fields.

In order for it pickup the change, I also changed the version Hash.  Now when the app starts it duly created the appropriate indexes and things work fast.

The problem is this is happening on every single launch.  Shouldn't this happen just once?

Comment: Are you calling [context save]?

Comment: well, yes, it's being called in `applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that applicationWillTerminate only gets called when your app is terminated from the background.  Maybe set a breakpoint to verify it's getting called, and consider moving it to applicationWillResignActive instead.

Comment: Yes, it's being called and the index are there even when the app quits.  It's just that it tries to do it again on the next launch.  Seems like it's not saving the versioning state somewhere so it doesn't know that this model has been migrated to the latest version.